# how to read the data from excel sheet using two @Test in same class in testng selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

In this below example program, is it possible to use two `@ test` in one class,and then i have to fetch the data from `excel sheet` for both `@ test` in same excel sheet.is it possible?.two methods can be used in same class? one excel can contains both data's of two`@ test`?.please give me some ideas or example to be used two @ test in same class fetching data from excel sheet. I am waiting for reply.please help me...thanks in advance.

```
public class Test1 {
    @BeforeTest
    @Test(groups = { "" }, dataProvider = "getTestData", description = "")
    public void abc(String a, String b) {
    }

    @Test(groups = { "" }, dataProvider = "", description = "")
    public void abcd(String c, String d) {
    }

    @AfterMethod
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getTestData() {
        check = true;
        return TestUtil.getData(Sprint1xls, this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the above is possible. I still don't get it where is the problem statement. Did you try above? is it failing? if yes then what is the error?
1) Yes, You can have 2 @Test methods in one class using same data provider. 
2) If in the same sheet if you are using same data for this tests then there is no problem at all. if there is different data for different test then in your data provider toggle between test data using method name.
Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I got this error.when im passing the parameter from the same excel sheet to both test in same class.                                                             Error:The data provider is trying to pass 4 parameters but the      method com.TestCases_Sprint1.twoMethods#_Sprint1_updaterole takes 1 ...thanks @ Mrunal

Comment: It seems your TestUtil.getData is returning 4 column values which align to 4 arguments to your @Test annotated method. If you can post minimal working code which can re-create this issue, i can look into it.